# "Add Action Strip" in NL animation panel is introducing mystery motion

Tags: animation

I have some unwanted foot movement in a standing character. I have looked for ages for the keyframes to adjust but can't find them. I then tried to add a "Copy Location" bone constraint to pin the foot to an empty but it still moves. I then thought of using the nonlinear editor to copy the action. Weirdly the unwanted foot motion comes back.

https://youtu.be/NEViNE4JLNE

Any ideas?

Comment: Too little infos to understand what's going on, maybe upload your file?

Comment: Ok - here is a more in depth video... https://youtu.be/-aUI1Z3BaFY

Comment: Here is my file... https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aF-Tzcoj0Sx8s619Q8DgmZffxvjYFCOM/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original armature and the problematic one aren't identical: the thigh bones have a different pivot point.

In this kind of rigs (pure FK) only the hip bone has loc infos, all the others bones are driven by rotations, and by parent-child relations.
If you move the pivot point of thoose rotations, the animation will start to be screwed up.

To solve, move in edit mode the heads of the thigh bones up on Z axis until they return to their original location (if this is compatible with your character)

If this is not possible, you have to either manually adjust the animation or (better) create an IK chain to lock the feet movements.

[image]